# 55.000 index pages, 404 cached versions

Tags: 404, google-cache

All pages are being 404 cached on google?

Currently we are using cloudflare, which I dont think is causing the problem, but you never know.

Does anyone know how to understand the problem and what is causing this? I will be ready to provide further information for you to understand the issue aswell.

Also, 1 year ago we switched from http to https.

And last:
If you take this URL
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PVvZbxO5Ru8J:https://bolte.dk/moetrikker+&cd=2&hl=da&ct=clnk&gl=dk

and change it to
https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PVvZbxO5Ru8J:https://www.bolte.dk/moetrikker+&cd=2&hl=da&ct=clnk&gl=dk

then it will display a cached version correct ( added the "www" )

I dont know where to continue to solve this issue now.

## Edit

SO I think I found out, if anyone are here with same issues, this might or I am sure its related to the new google MFI (Mobile First Index), since this has been enabled the error 404-cached version has been around, also google is saying this is the reason why alot of us are experiencing this issue.

read more [here](https://twitter.com/Marie_Haynes/status/1042470296119390208)

Comment: "1 year ago we switched from http to https" - This may not be the cause of this specific problem, but your site does not appear to be redirecting properly. eg. `https://www.example.com` first redirects to `http://example.com` (note: HTTP!) and then back to `https` via a 2nd redirect. If you request `http://www.example.com` then this redirects to `https://www.example.com` which is then followed by the two redirects above, resulting in 3 redirects! Also, have you added all 4 properties to GSC and specified the appropriate www/non-www preference?

Comment: Where did you find out how the redirect works for the specific site, maybe i could use this to check/valid if has proper setup ?

Comment: I used Google Chrome (desktop). Specifically, the “Network” tab of the “Object Inspector” (Developer Tools) that is built in to the browser. Most mainstream desktop browsers have something similar.

Comment: Edit: Nevermind i see your point.

Comment: So i have purged/flushed all pages from cloudflare, this seems to fix the redirect issues. Now I need to check if this solve the cache issue on google. Thank you for pointing this out. 

If this issue is related to the cache issue on google i will let you know.

Comment: Right, the redirect should be fixed, but unfortunately the 404 cached version remains on google. 

Now i might have found out why, not sure - i did a test yesterday http://www.seotools.com/seo-cloaking-checker/ which flagged out site on google as cloaking, but only if i type it with https://ourdomain.com but without "https://" it is not flagged. Not sure what it is trying to tell me here, and what is causing the cloaking. hmm